# How to add a default endpoint behaviors to all services

Tags: wcf, endpoints, endpointbehavior

I'm attempting to add an endpoint behavior to all services of a host.

So for example, I have a couple of .svc ServiceHost declarations and I want to know how I would be able to configure this via Web.config.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom class derived from ServiceHost and custom class derived from ServiceHostFactory. In your custom ServiceHost implementation add needed behaviors. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) you have example.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but see if this helps -

```
foreach (var endPoint in mySvcHost.Description.Endpoints)
{
    endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's untested but I think if you add an EndpointBehavior with no name to the Advanced->Endpoint Behavior (in the WCF config tool), then it's done for all service endpoints (unless overriden).

The same thing works for the Service Behaviors (that's what I'm using so I know that works).

Comment: Yes, this is part of the Simplified Configuration starting with .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how my custom endpoint behavior was getting applied without my endpoint actually referencing it!